# How to scale the logo block to fit exactly in the navbar?

Tags: html, css

this is a problem only in mobile. here's the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvS77.png

this is the navbar html:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="/" class="logo">LOGO</a>
    <a href="/example">example</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mob()">
    <i class="bars">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.bars div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.topnav .logo {
  float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

p.s. the responsive class is added with javascript when the three bars in mobile is clicked

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are you expecting to see? It's hard to test this since you didn't include the link to the actual image.

Comment: thanks, here's the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvS77.png

Answer (score 2):

I added this css

```
.topnav .logo {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav {
   display: flex;
}
```

Is this something you want?

Don't use float in your css. We have amazing css properties `flexbox` for layouting. Float destroys layouting.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.bars div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav .logo {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
 }

   .topnav .logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <div class="logo">
      <a href="/" class="">LOGO</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/example">example</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mob()">
    <i class="bars">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: but now the logo isn't in the left and you can click it everywhere and in mobile the logo text is on top of the example link text when I click the three bars

Comment: thanks a lot but I fixed it just by adding 9px of margin